# How to search on a document and get results, from the results I would like to check out the document and edit metadata?

Tags: document-library, search-results

I am using sp 2010. I have a document library with many documents. On my document library I have a search box in the right top corner. When I enter some name of my document I got 4 results. I find one relevant document. I would like to check out this document and edit the meta data. But on my search result page I can only click on the title to open the document directy.

When I go to the document library I can also not filter on the column name.

So what is the best practice to find some specific document, check it out and edit the meta data?

Answer (score 3):

The ideal way is to edit the document library view and add additional columns on which you can filter and find the document.

Another option is to modify the search results webpart and enhance the results view to add an extra link to (Edit/View) document properties.

Here is a sample XSLT I took from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougperkes/archive/2009/05/13/sharepoint-search-results-adding-a-link-to-the-view-properties-page-of-a-document.aspx) site

```
<!-- A custom template to display a link to view the properties for a document -->
<xsl:template name="DisplayViewPropertiesLink">
  <xsl:param name="itemUrl" />
  <xsl:param name="siteUrl" />
  <xsl:param name="listItemId" />
  <xsl:param name="contentclass" />
  <xsl:if test="$contentclass='STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary'">
    <xsl:variable name="docLibLoc" select="substring-before(substring-after($itemUrl, concat($siteUrl, '/')), '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="viewPropUrl" select="concat($siteUrl, '/', $docLibLoc, '/Forms/DispForm.aspx?id=', $listItemId)" />
    - <a href="{$viewPropUrl}">View Properties</a>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:call-template name="DisplayString">
  <xsl:with-param name="str" select="write" />
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:call-template name="DisplayViewPropertiesLink">
  <xsl:with-param name="itemUrl" select="url" />
  <xsl:with-param name="siteUrl" select="sitename" />
  <xsl:with-param name="listItemId" select="listitemid" />
  <xsl:with-param name="contentclass" select="contentclass" />
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:call-template name="DisplayCollapsingStatusLink">
```

Similart XSLT's you can also download from http://sctxsl.codeplex.com/releases/view/12070

Answer (score 0):

Can you not find the document via All files --> Document library and edit its metadata from there?